# Convenient way to scope application to a current_project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have an application that scopes everything under a `Project`. All the views require the project to be available. This allows me to have a `current_project` method:

```
current_project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id)
```

While this is convenient, it means my routes always have to be scoped under project, and I can't use shallow routing. This can be nasty when you have four levels of nesting.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :posts do
    resources :attachments
    resources :comments do
      resources :attachments
    end
  end
end
```

This much nesting means complicated routes and complicated tests:

```
form_for [@project, @post, @comment, @attachment] ...
```

It also means a lot of duplication since polymorphic models like `attachments` must work for `posts` and `comments` that are nested at different levels.

```
form_for [@project, @attachable, @attachment] # ... for posts
form_for [@project, @post, @attachable, @attachment] # ... for comments
```

So I switched to using shallow routes. It's such a relief, but this has another nasty side effect:

The `current_project` is no longer easily attainable. To get it for an `Attachment`, for example, I need to go through three parents:

```
@attachment.comment.post.project
```

And since all the views need it, I need do this in almost every action.

```
@project = @post.project
@project = @comment.post.project
@project = @attachment.comment.post.project
```

Is there some middle ground where I can have a convenient `current_project` method without having to nest my routes 4 levels? I don't want to use subdomains either.

Comment: is it too obvious to suggest adding methods so you can do `@comment.project` and `@attachment.project`?

Comment: Is the `:project_id` param available after logging in ? You could use  it to persist it in the session and create some hook in your `ApplicationController` that brings an instance variable containing the `Project` object found through the id. Do you think it could be done in your scenario ? I could provide an answer pointing to this process.

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco No, it's not. They are usually greeted with a list of projects that they usually select from.

Comment: @tokland that's one way to do it, but it doesn't solve the problem. It just hides it. I'm still reaching through three models, but I've hidden the implementation instead.

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco suppose I made the `:project_id` persist in the session, what answer did you have in mind?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Well, if you have `:project_id` in session is just a matter of create a hook before the desired actions setting an instance variable with the current project, something like: `@current_project ||= Project.find(session[:project_id])`. It will be available in all views, without that awful **demeter violation** that you've pointed out. Sounds good ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this more, i think it would be better to save current_project_id into the users table, so that when someone switches project you update their record.  Then, your current_project method is just

```
#application.rb
def current_project
  @current_project ||= current_user.current_project
end
```

You'll need to add

```
#user.rb
belongs_to :current_project, :class_name => "Project"
```

and, on any page load, you always know which project you're dealing with, just by looking in the users table with this method.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I think I'll try it. I'm not sure how it plays out with friendly forwarding, or automatically accessing a link via the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
#in app/controllers/application.rb
def current_project
  unless @current_project
    @current_project = (@post && @post.project) || (@comment && @comment.post.project) || (@attachment && @attachment.comment.post.project)
  end
  @current_project
end
```

I use the instance variable @current_project inside the method so that if current_project is called multiple times in a single action/render it only has to do the calculation once: the subsequent times it will just read it out of @current_project.

Comment: I have to say, that's not ideal, but at least it puts everything in one place. That said, this method requires you add new logic for each object... let me mull it over.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a before_action that loads @current_project to each controller.

Comment: I'm already sort of trying that. I was hoping for something cleaner.